# How MLN and MaxEnt are different?

Tags: maximum-entropy, markov-logic-network

To me it seems that MLN (Markov logic network) and MaxEnt (Maximum Entropy classifier) solve the same formula:
$$ p(y|x) = \frac{exp(\sum_i \lambda_if_i(x,y))}{\sum_y exp(\sum_i \lambda_if_i(x,y))} $$

Then, how both models are different?